# Having trouble with my codes using JOINS for 3 tables

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I need to Create a report that will display the following: FIRSTNAME, SALARY with additional 1000 rename the column as BONUS, get the DEPARTMENT_NAME, DEPARTMENT_ID and CITY. Use ON condition to connect the three tables.

What's the proper query for this?

i'm currently using Oracle 12c for this.
One of the codes i tried.

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, SALARY, CITY, DEPARTMENT_NAME, DEPARTMENT_ID
FROM EMPLOYEES
JOIN LOCATIONS AND DEPARTMENTS ON DEPARTMENT_NAME=DEPARTMENT_ID;
```

CODES FOR TABLES

```
    CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES(
EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(10),
LASTNAME VARCHAR(10)NOT NULL,
JOB_ID VARCHAR(10),
SALARY NUMBER(8,2),
MANAGER_ID NUMBER(6),
DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER(4));
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (100,'STEVEN','KING','AD_PRES',24000,NULL,90);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (101,'NENA','KOCHAR','AD_VP',17000,100,90);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (102,'LEX','DE HAAN','AD_VP',17000,100,90);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (103,'ALEXANDER','HUNOLD','IT_PROG',NULL,101,60);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (104,'BRUCE','ERNST','IT_PROG',6000,102,60);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (107,'DIANA','LORENTZ','IT_PROG',4200,103,60);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (124,'KEVIN','MOURGOS','ST_MAN',5800,100,50);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (141,'TRINA','RAJS','ST_CLERK',3500,124,50);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (142,'CURTIS','DAVIES','ST_CLERK',3100,124,50);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (143,'RANDALL','MATOS','ST_CLERK',2600,124,50);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (144,'PETER','VARGAS','ST_CLERK',2500,124,50);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (149,'ELENI','ZLOTKEY','SA_MAN',10500,100,80);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (174,'ELLEN','ABEL','SA_REP',11000,149,50);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (176,'JONATHAN','TAYLOR','SA_REP',8600,149,80);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (178,'KIMBERLEY','GRANT','SA_REP',7000,149,NULL);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (200, 'JENNIFER','WHALEN','AD_ASST',4400,101,10);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (201,'MICHAEL','HARTSTEIN','MK_MAN',13000,100,20);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (202,'PAT','FAY','MK_REP',6000,201,20);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (205,'SHELLEY','HIGGINS','AC_MGR',12000,101,110);

    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (206,'WILLIAM','GIETZ','AC_ACCOUNT',8300,205,110);

    CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENTS(
DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
DEPARTMENT_NAME VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
MANAGER_ID NUMBER(6),
LOCATION_ID NUMBER(4),
CONSTRAINT fk_locid FOREIGN KEY (LOCATION_ID)
REFERENCES LOCATIONS(LOCATION_ID));
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS VALUES(10,'ADMINISTRATION',200,1700);
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS VALUES(20,'MARKETING',201,1800);
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS VALUES(50,'SHIPPING',124,1500);
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS VALUES(60,'IT',103,1400);
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS VALUES(80,'SALES',149,2500);
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS VALUES(90,'EXECUTIVE',100,1700);
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS VALUES(100,'ACCOUNTING',205,1700);
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS VALUES(190,'CONTRACTING',NULL,1700);
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS VALUES(110,'HRD',205,1800);
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS VALUES(1115,'CUSTOMER',NULL,2500);

    CREATE TABLE LOCATIONS(
LOCATION_ID NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
STREET_ADDRESS VARCHAR(20),
POSTAL_CODE VARCHAR(10),
CITY VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
STATE_PROVINCE VARCHAR(10),
COUNTRY_ID CHAR(2));
INSERT INTO LOCATIONS VALUES(1400, '2014 JABBERWACKY RD',26192, 'SOUTHLAKE', 'TEXAS', 'US');
INSERT INTO LOCATIONS VALUES(1500, '2011 INTERIORS RD',99236, 'SAN FRANCISCO', 'CALIFORNIA', 'US');
INSERT INTO LOCATIONS VALUES(1700, '2004 CHARADE RD',98199, 'SEATLE', 'WASHINGTON', 'US');
INSERT INTO LOCATIONS VALUES(1800, '460 BLOOR ST.','ON M5S', 'TORONTO', 'ONTARIO', 'CA');
INSERT INTO LOCATIONS VALUES(2500, 'MAGDALEN CENTER','OX 9ZB', 'OXFORD', 'OXFORD', 'UK');
INSERT INTO LOCATIONS VALUES(2400, '365 SEATLE','ST 99W', 'OXFORD', 'OXFORD', 'US');
```

I expect the things that i typed but got an error of "missing keyword"

Answer (score 0):

`AND` doesn't belong in a `JOIN` clause.  It is not a relational operator.

Presumably, you intend:

```
SELECT e.FIRSTNAME, e.SALARY, l.CITY, 
       d.DEPARTMENT_NAME, d.DEPARTMENT_ID
FROM EMPLOYEES e JOIN
     DEPARTMENTS d
     ON e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID JOIN
     LOCATIONS l
     ON d.LOCATION_ID = l.LOCATION_ID;
```

Notice that in addition to fixing `AND LOCATION`, I introduced table aliases and qualified column names.  Your `ON` clause was simply wrong.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f7fecb57c316736f6042b69b16a29ba1) is a db<>fiddle illustrating that the syntax works.

Comment: SQL> SELECT e.FIRSTNAME, e.SALARY, e.CITY,
  2         d.DEPARTMENT_NAME, d.DEPARTMENT_ID
  3  FROM EMPLOYEES e JOIN
  4       DEPARTMENTS d
  5       ON e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID;
     ON e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID
                          *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00904: "D"."DEPARTMENT_ID": invalid identifier